# Title does no appear for Xamarin when page launched in root

Tags: xamarin

in my root page, I have two things occur. First thing is loading the dashboard, then I Navigate to the intent, which is basically pushing another page.

RootPage.xaml.cs

```
public RootPage()
{
     ....
     Detail = new DashboardPage();
     NavigateToIntent();
}

public async void NavigateToIntent()
{
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new ContactPage())

}
```

The issue I'm coming across is that the page will load all the content, but the title will not appear. Even when I hardcode ContactPage's Title. Hypothetically if I didn't trigger NavigateToIntent with Rootpage constructor, and instead triggered it off a button click on DashBoard Page, it works fine and title is populated. Was wondering if I can get some tips or guidance to get the title to appear.

Comment: Did you set `NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false" ` in your DashboardPage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing more code, I think the difference is where you are navigating FROM. Since you are setting a `Detail` property, it seems you are calling `await Navigation.PushAsync(new ContactPage())` from the `MasterDetailPage`. However if you navigate from a button click with a button that is in the `DashboardPage` then you would be calling `await Navigation.PushAsync(new ContactPage())` from the `Detail` page rather than from the root `MasterDetailPage`, IOW you are replacing your `MasterDetailPage` with the `ContactPage` rather than replacing the `Detail` `DashboardPage` with the `ContactPage`.

If I am correct, and you want that navigation to happen automatically, you can navigate to the `ContactPage` from `DashboardPage`'s `OnAppearing` override.

However I can not be certain without seeing more code.